# UIPopoverController arrow not the same white as my UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uipopovercontroller

So the problem that I have is my `UIPopoverController`'s arrow is a different color to my `UINavigationBar` color. If you look at the image there is a slight shadow on the white and you can see it is not the same white:

[image]

This only happens on iOS 8 and not on 7, on 7 it's working as expected.

```
- (UIPopoverController *)showPopoverController:(UIViewController *)controller fromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)view
{
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];

    //  controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    appDelegate.popoverController = popoverController;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(controller.view.frame.size.width, controller.view.frame.size.height + 44.0);
    [navController setPreferredContentSize:size];
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:size];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [navController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [popoverController setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    return popoverController;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I needed this little piece of code

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in this line

```
[popoverController setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Color of arrow is the background color of UIPopoverController